# Passing parameters from model to controller in razor application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem in my asp.net mvc4 application :

i'am passing two integers as a parameteres to an action :

```
<a>@Html.ActionLink(s, "Gerer_Sequence", "Travail", new { seq = Model[k][i].Id_séquence , affa = aff.Id_affaire } )</a>
```

the action is :

```
public ActionResult Gerer_Sequence(int seq,  int affa)
{
    Session["affaire"] = affa;
    Session["sequence"] = seq;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Calendar");
}
```

the problem is that the parameters are `null` however the its values are `3` and `1` in the model.

So what is the problem? How can i modify my code to fix the error?

Comment: do you see the parameters in the qs of the link?

Comment: What do you mean `null` ? Did you mean they default (`0`) ?

Comment: btw, that <a> around .ActionLink is not needed, avoid that.

Comment: i think this is only problem <a>

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML this line generated? All should become answerable with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put the action in the same controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Gerer Sequence", "Gerer_Sequence", new { seq = Model[k][i].Id_séquence , affa = aff.Id_affaire } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("EditUser", "Index", new { Id = m.ID,Name = m.Name })
                    </td>


  public ActionResult Index(string Id, string Name)
        {
            var model = new RegisterModel();
            int _ID = 0;
            int.TryParse(Id, out _ID);
            if (_ID > 0)
            {
                RegisterModel register = GetRegisterUserById(_ID);
                model.ID = _ID;
                model.Name = register.Name;
                model.Address = register.Address;
                model.PhoneNo = register.PhoneNo;

            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Remove you <a> tag and try this.
@Html.ActionLink("s", "Gerer_Sequence", "Travail", new { seq = Model[k][i].Id_séquence , affa = aff.Id_affaire } )

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change this:

```
new { seq = Model[k][i].Id_séquence , affa = aff.Id_affaire }
```

to this:

```
new RouteValueDictionary { { "seq", Model[k][i].Id_séquence }, { "affa", aff.Id_affaire } }
```

because the fourth parameter you're using is the route values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(s, "Gerer_Sequence", "Travail", new { seq = Model[k][i].Id_séquence , affa = aff.Id_affaire }, null )
```

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the  tag
- Ensure that parameters you have provided are int values.
- After that run your application and check the link generated, if values are ok then it should be ok.